# Polar coordinate transformation

Tags: plotting

I have a function in polar coordinate
     `f[\[Theta],\[Phi]] = 1 + 2 Cos[2 \[Theta]]`. 
The function is centered at the origin. Is there a way to plot another function of the same shape but centered at (1,0,0), i.e. shifted along x-axis?  What I want is to have two functions of identical shape centered at (0,0,0) and (1,0,0) respectively but I only have the explicit form of the function at (0,0,0).

```
SphericalPlot3D[1 + 2 Cos[2 \[Theta]], 
{\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** Changed colors and corrected color issues.

```
sp3d = SphericalPlot3D[
   1 + 2 Cos[2 θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi},
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
     Piecewise[{{Red, 1 + 2 Cos[2 θ] < 0}}, Lighter@Orange]],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
   PlotPoints -> 25,
   MaxRecursion -> 3];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  sp3d,
  ReplacePart[
   sp3d, {1, 1} -> 
     sp3d[[1, 1]] /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ} :> {x + offset, 
      y, z}],
  PlotRange -> All], {{offset, 1}, 0, 3, 0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your solution runs much faster. Can you explain your solution a bit? /. is the replaceall operator and :> is rule delayed. What does _?NumericQ do here? Thanks.

Comment: It restricts the lists that are translated by `{0, 0, 1}` to those whose third coordinate is a numeric value. The first two coordinates are already restricted to being numeric by being bound to within the interval `{-1, 1}`. The `Graphics3D` contains other lists of length three that are not points and should not be translated.

Comment: How to change the color setting so that the plot is yellow when 1+2Cos[\[Theta]] is positive and red for negative? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

First generate data points from your function:

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{1 + 2 Cos[2 \[Theta]], \[Theta], \[Phi]}, 
    {\[Theta], 0, Pi, Pi/500}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/500}], 1];
```

Next a mapping from polar to cartesian:

```
mapping = 
 CoordinateTransformData["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", "Mapping"];
```

now the points (transformed) with offset of `{1,0,0}`:

```
ListPointPlot3D[# + {1, 0, 0} & /@ (mapping /@ data), 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

or

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[# + {1, 0, 0} & /@ (mapping /@ data),
 MaxPlotPoints -> 60,
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Both together:

```
mappeddata = mapping /@ data;
plt1 = ListSurfacePlot3D[# + {1, 0, 0} & /@ mappeddata,
   MaxPlotPoints -> 30, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Red}];
plt2 = ListSurfacePlot3D[mappeddata,
   MaxPlotPoints -> 30, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], Blue}];
Show[plt1, plt2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could you post the code for plotting two functions at the same time using ListSurfacePlot3D? I tried ListSurfacePlot3D[{# & /@ (mapping /@ data), # + {1, 0, 0} & /@ (mapping /@ data)}, MaxPlotPoints -> 60,
 BoxRatios -> Automatic]. But it doesn't work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

For exact copies apply [`Translate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Translate.html) to the graphics elements, which are in position `1` of the graphics returned by plotting functions:

```
g = SphericalPlot3D[1 + 2 Cos[2 θ], {θ, 0, Pi}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}];
vecs = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};

Show[MapAt[Translate[#, vecs] &, g, 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It's very efficient, as `g` is computed once, only one copy is stored, and the translations are computed by the GPU (I think).

```
vecs = 2 Tuples[{Range[0, 3], Range[0, 2], {0}}];
g12 = Show[MapAt[Translate[#, vecs] &, g, 1], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
ByteCount /@ {g, g12}
(*  {697504, 698024}  *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @yquan You're welcome.